# Localhost jquery.google-search-master console error - $.GoogleSearch is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, autocomplete

I have a localhost server on port 3000 which I set up using node.js and express to run a website locally. I'm quite new to coding in general and learned these frameworks only recently, so I might be missing crucial understanding of concepts, but I've reached a dead end after much searching online.

I want to manipulate data from google searches thought my website, specifically to get a cityname data from a form, send it to a google search, and then get the data back. For now I only want to console.log that returned data to see what it tells me, and for that I found this nice repository:

https://github.com/sdepold/jquery.google-search#license

After downloading the ZIP, I tried to incorporate the files into my own folder hierarchy, copying the files into my own folders as such:

I placed jquery.google-search.min.js, jquery-1.7.2.min.js, jquery.google-search.spec.js, jquery.google-search.js, and buster.js into my js folder under 'public'.

all of these are files that were in the ZIP which i placed into my folders, but some other files were there like '.travis.yml' or 'package.json' or 'compiler.jar' which I didn't copy. I have my own package.json file which contains the following:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.15.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "nodemailer": "2.5.0",
    "express": "~4.13.4",
    "ejs": "~2.4.2",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  }
}
```

and the package.json in the jquery.google-search was:

```
{
  "author": "Sascha Depold <sascha@depold.com> (htp://depold.com)",
  "name": "jquery.google-search",
  "description": "Execute google searches within your client-side javascript.",
  "version": "0.1.4",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/sdepold/jquery.google-search",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/sdepold/jquery.google-search.git"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "jquery.skeleton": "~0.6.0",
    "buster": "~0.6.2"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {},
  "engines": {
    "node": "*"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npm run minify && npm run buster-test",
    "buster-test": "node_modules/.bin/buster-test",
    "buster-capture": "(npm run buster-server &) && sleep 2 && npm run buster-capture-browser",
    "minify": "java -jar dist/compiler.jar src/*.js --js_output_file=dist/jquery.`pwd|sed -e 's/.*jquery\\.//'`.min.js",
    "buster-capture-browser": "type -P open &>/dev/null && open 'http://localhost:1111/capture' || firefox 'http://localhost:1111/capture'",
    "buster-server": "node_modules/.bin/buster-server"
  },
  "main": "src/jquery.google-search.js"
}
```

I don't know if I should have copied the other files or done something with the json... it might not even be the issue. There is also a file called 'MIT-LICENSE' which i'm not sure is needed.. ?

In any case, once i start my server and go to my Localhost, and I write some text into the form, the console (I have Firefox) displays:

[Constructor Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xScKW.png)

For finding a city through a form I used the geobytes autocomplete widget.

My relevant code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.google-search.js">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- Autocomplete Cities -->
    <script>
    jQuery( function () {
      var find;

      function getCityDetails (cityname) {  //this is a function I created
        jQuery.getJSON(
          "http://gd.geobytes.com/GetCityDetails?callback=?&fqcn="+cityname,
            function searchGoogle (data) {
              find = new $.GoogleSearch().search(city + " weather", {}, function(data) {
              console.log(find);
              })
            }
         );
      }

     jQuery("#f_elem_city").autocomplete({

      source: function (request, response) {
       jQuery.getJSON(
        "http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity?callback=?&q="+request.term,
        function (data) {
          response(data);
        }
       );
      },
      minLength: 3,
      select: function (event, ui) {
       var selectedObj = ui.item;
       jQuery("#f_elem_city").val(selectedObj.value);
       getCityDetails(selectedObj.value); //this is a function I created
       return false;
      },
      open: function () {
       jQuery(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
      },
      close: function () {
       jQuery(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
      }

     });

     jQuery("#f_elem_city").autocomplete("option", "delay", 100);

    });
  </script>
```

I'm assuming my problem is in my getCityDetails or searchGoogle functions, in its parameters or its placement that in some way doesn't fit with the stack order or it is a sort of closure which prevents me from doing what I want, but in general you can see I copied the Google.Search code from the repository, therefore there should not be a problem to create that object...

Furthermore, since the error points to jquery.min.js, and it's a minified file, I don't know where the problem lies, but it seems to be related to the autocomplete feature, not the google search.

I'm quite stumped here since trying to debug this any further is beyond my knowledge level at the moment... All help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sdepold who created the https://github.com/sdepold/jquery.google-search#license repository alerted me to the fact that the Google API concerning this search functionality is depricated, therefore unusable in this way.